# Can I Use External SSD with Type-C for Bootable Windows Effectively

Tags: external-hard-drive

If I install Windows 10 on a external SSD with Type-C connector like Samsung T5 1TB and use it with my laptop (which also has a Type-C connector) effectively?

Can I play games on it without significant performance loss?

Comment: You can, but there are caveats: Windows is not meant to be hot-swapped, nor does it support it, so you can only use the external SSD with a single PC; You're at the mercy of the USB cable and there's always a chance the cable could be accidentally bumped, resulting in a hard reset. I personally would never use an external drive to run an OS like Windows, however, others have done so successfully and there are answers on Superuser regarding this.  Also keep in mind how you're going to ensure the T5 doesn't overheat, as the SSD's chips themselves will get quite hot when under continuous I/O load

Comment: Installing Windows on an external drive would violate the EULA, wouldn't it?